# How to get started with spacy library and its module in Google Colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, spacy, spacy-transformers

I'm facing problem with `Spacy` module to load in `colab` GPU notebook.

```
!python -m spacy download en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg
```

This command works for `anaconda` notebook to download, but how to download in Google `Colab` and load module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [crazyelf](/questions/tagged/crazyelf) for the support. Finally i got the solution for this question.

Following are the steps:

1) !pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg-2.2.0/en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg-2.2.0.tar.gz

2) It will ask to restart runtime. Do that.

3) import spacy
   import spacy_transformers

nlp = spacy.load('en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg')
   print("Done")

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Update Spacy before loading module, it's a known bug of Spacy version in Colab.

```
!pip install --upgrade spacy
```

(Found it here https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers/issues/83)

Comment: Hello CrazyElf, I have performed (1) !pip install --upgrade spacy (2)on -m spacy download en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg (3)dataFrac=data.sample(frac=1.00)

is_using_gpu = spacy.prefer_gpu()
if is_using_gpu:
    torch.set_default_tensor_type("torch.cuda.FloatTensor")

nlp = spacy.load('en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg') staps in sequence. Still getting the "[E050] Can't find model 'en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory."

Comment: I found where Spacy downloaded it. Try to load package from there: nlp = spacy.load('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg/en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg-2.2.0')

Comment: Still getting "Can't find model '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg/en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg-2.2.0'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory."

Comment: Use the following kink for the more details (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LHKgy0SVIvKRuf23UtuTe5YvNAVD5Ffj)

Comment: Do you use Python3 or Python2 runtime on Colab?

Comment: And try to find downloaded package by yourself: !find / -name en_trf_xlnetbasecased_lg -print

Comment: When you find it, you should look deeper in founded folder until you find folder 'tokenizer'. Then you should use full folder path until 'tokenizer' in spacy.load, it works in my case. I have Python3 runtime.

Comment: I also have same version of python.