# spacy.training module not found in collab

Tags: nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Code is running properly in local windows machine but gives error while importing spacy.training in collab
what can be the problem?

```
from spacy.training import Example

    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ebc5aa3cff21> in <module>()
      3 from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding
      4 from pathlib import Path
----> 5 from spacy.training import Example
      6 # TRAINING THE MODEL
      7 with nlp.disable_pipes(*unaffected_pipes):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.training'
```

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484501/how-to-get-started-with-spacy-library-and-its-module-in-google-colab).

Answer (score 0):

I believe You have `spacy 2` on your colab.

You need to import spacy with all the modules again on colab.

It is independent from Windows spacy.

You can check your version of spacy and update it using below instructions:

Run this command on your Jupyter cell:

`!pip show spacy`

OR

`spacy.__version__`

Once you check the version, you can  update to a latest version by:

`!pip install -U spacy`

Once, you get `spacy 3` your problem will be resolved.

`Example` was introduced in `spacy version 3`.

Link to `Example` :

https://spacy.io/api/example#_title

Make sure to `Restart Runtime` from the menu bar in colab.